# IF works, SWITCH not

Tags: jquery

```
    <input type="text" name="importo_estratto" />
    <input type="text" name="numeri_giocati" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=submit]').click(function() {
        var importo_estratto = $('input[name=importo_estratto]').val();
        var numeri_giocati = $('input[name=numeri_giocati]').val();

        // ESTRATTO
        if (importo_estratto != '') {
            switch(numeri_giocati) {
                case 1: paga = 11.23; break;
                case 2: paga = 5.62; break;
                case 3: paga = 3.74; break;
                case 4: paga = 2.81; break;
                case 5: paga = 2.25; break;
                case 6: paga = 1.87; break;
                case 7: paga = 1.60; break;
                case 8: paga = 1.40; break;
                case 9: paga = 1.25; break;
                case 10: paga = 1.12; break;
            }

            /*if (numeri_giocati == 1) {
                var paga = 11.23;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 2) {
                var paga = 5.62;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 3) {
                var paga = 3.74;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 4) {
                var paga = 2.81;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 5) {
                var paga = 2.25;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 6) {
                var paga = 1.87;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 7) {
                var paga = 1.60;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 8) {
                var paga = 1.40;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 9) {
                var paga = 1.25;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 10) {
                var paga = 1.12;
            }*/

            alert(paga);
        } else {
            var tot_estratto = 0;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I need your help.
I don't know why, but the IF works and the SWITCH not.
The alert outputs "undefined" instead of the value "paga", but everything seems to be ok for me.

Can someone help me, please?
Thank you very much

Comment: You should define paga and add a default in switch.

Comment: Does it work with `case "1":`...?

Comment: I didn't make it an answer, I'm suggesting to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Algorithmic Solution

Nobody has noticed that, with the stated values of `paga`, an algorithmic solution is available.

For numeri_giocati > 0, the value of `paga` is given by the formula:

- paga = 11.23 / numeri_giocati

[Here's my verification](http://jsfiddle.net/85Xg8/5/) that the algorithm gives the correct values (to 2 decimal places over the range numeri_giocati = 1 to 10).

The algorithm can be implemented with a javascript function `genPaga(seme, n)`, where seme is the seed (or scalar) value 11.23, and n is a positive integer.

The code in the question thus becomes :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function genPaga(seme, n) {
        return (seme / n).toFixed(2);
    }

    $('input[name=submit]').click(function() {
        var importo_estratto = $('input[name=importo_estratto]').val();
        var numeri_giocati = parseInt($('input[name=numeri_giocati]').val(), 10);
        var paga, tot_estratto;//??
        if (importo_estratto != '' && !isNaN(numeri_giocati) && numeri_giocati >= 1) {
            paga = genPaga(11.23, numeri_giocati);
        } else {
            tot_estratto = 0;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that you're not limited to the range of values hard-coded in a switch/case statement. Say one day you wish to cater for numeri_giocati = 11, 12, 13 etc. The algorithm will handle that automatically. The function `genPaga()` is also available to be called elsewhere in the code if necessary.

The limitation is that you are bound by the algorithm. If an algorithm were not available (or could not be deduced), then a switch/case may be the only alternative.

Comment: Man you are the smartest guy in the world!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: We, I've always known that. It's taken the best part of a lifetime for someone else to notice. :)

Answer (score 6):

Make numeri_giocati numeric, it is taken as string and switch fails to match with number. You can make it number by unary + operator. You can also use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` instead of using unary plus.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LgMFR/)**

```
switch(+numeri_giocati) {
                case 1: paga = 11.23; break;
                case 2: paga = 5.62; break;
                case 3: paga = 3.74; break;
                case 4: paga = 2.81; break;
                case 5: paga = 2.25; break;
                case 6: paga = 1.87; break;
                case 7: paga = 1.60; break;
                case 8: paga = 1.40; break;
                case 9: paga = 1.25; break;
                case 10: paga = 1.12; break;
            }
```

Comment: @Xander: It's perfectly nice, and not really implicit for all intents and purposes. (I mean, the unary `+` operator doesn't do anything except cast, so...)

Comment: +1 ***nice*** way to cast, really isn't implicit since you're (explicitly using the `+` operator to convert)

Comment: Thank you! Can someone explain me what is an "implicit cast"?
I also tried the solution of @Xander and it works well, so what was the real problem?

Comment: implicit/explicit cast - https://www.google.com/search?q=implicit+cast&aq=f&oq=implicit+cast

Comment: Yes, he just googled it for you. That's him trying to give you an hint as to how to handle those kinds of (simple) questions.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements in JavaScript don't perform type conversions.

```
switch(numeri_giocati) {
    case '1': paga = 11.23; break;
    case '2': paga = 5.62; break;
    case '3': paga = 3.74; break;
    case '4': paga = 2.81; break;
    case '5': paga = 2.25; break;
    case '6': paga = 1.87; break;
    case '7': paga = 1.60; break;
    case '8': paga = 1.40; break;
    case '9': paga = 1.25; break;
    case '10': paga = 1.12; break;
}
```

Or,

```
var foo = parseInt(numeri_giocati);
switch(foo) {
    case 1: paga = 11.23; break;
    case 2: paga = 5.62; break;
    case 3: paga = 3.74; break;
    case 4: paga = 2.81; break;
    case 5: paga = 2.25; break;
    case 6: paga = 1.87; break;
    case 7: paga = 1.60; break;
    case 8: paga = 1.40; break;
    case 9: paga = 1.25; break;
    case 10: paga = 1.12; break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I would like to know what was the real problem: the "implicit cast" or the type conversion?

Answer (score 0):

you have to define `var paga` before the switch and make `numeri_giocati` numeric

like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=submit]').click(function() {
        var importo_estratto = $('input[name=importo_estratto]').val();
        var numeri_giocati = $('input[name=numeri_giocati]').val();

        // ESTRATTO
        var paga = 0;
        if (importo_estratto != '') {
            switch(+numeri_giocati) {
                case 1: paga = 11.23; break;
                case 2: paga = 5.62; break;
                case 3: paga = 3.74; break;
                case 4: paga = 2.81; break;
                case 5: paga = 2.25; break;
                case 6: paga = 1.87; break;
                case 7: paga = 1.60; break;
                case 8: paga = 1.40; break;
                case 9: paga = 1.25; break;
                case 10: paga = 1.12; break;
            }

            /*if (numeri_giocati == 1) {
                var paga = 11.23;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 2) {
                var paga = 5.62;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 3) {
                var paga = 3.74;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 4) {
                var paga = 2.81;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 5) {
                var paga = 2.25;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 6) {
                var paga = 1.87;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 7) {
                var paga = 1.60;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 8) {
                var paga = 1.40;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 9) {
                var paga = 1.25;
            } else if (numeri_giocati == 10) {
                var paga = 1.12;
            }*/

            alert(paga);
        } else {
            var tot_estratto = 0;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah, after you took the implicit cast bit from the @adil. defining `var paga` before the switch isn't the problem. it just re-scopes the variable `paga`.

Comment: I'm asking what is the problem with ``implicit cast``

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the implicit cast. You got the downvote before you edited the answer to include it (when the answer was in fact wrong).